# Table-row border is invisible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bordered table class to style a table.

However, for some of the rows, I need to change the left-border of a table cell yet retain the appearance of a border around the whole table.

To do this, I have tried to re-style the table cell left-border and add a left-border to the table row.

I can remove the table cell left-border, however the new table row left-border is invisible.

```
.table tr.topic_row {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}

.table td.topic_title {
    border-left: none;
}
```

You can see that the table-row border-appears to be invisible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5lsO.png

And yet it should be there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMQA.png

Any advice on how i can get the table row border to be visible would be greatly appreciated :)

---

Edit for clarification:

The issue here is, why isn't the table row border showing. Even though it should be there it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.table tr.topic_row td {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}

.table td.topic_title {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the border color to the first table cell in the row rather than the table row itself:

```
.topic_row td:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: But I need the table cell to have another border. 2 borders in total. So I need to apply a border to both. Sorry, if I wasn't clear when I removed the table cell border, I actually want to add a larger border to it as well, but I removed it just to demonstrate my issue with the table row.